# show route between multiple Annotations

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to show route (path) between multiple annotations.they are located at different locations but in a range of say 10 km.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out with this tutorial [link](http://navarra.ca/?p=786), it shows only single route between two points. you need to change as per your requirement. for 10km distance. you have to calculate distance using both point's (latitude, longitude).

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be helpful for you as i have done this for drawing rout between cities.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D firstCoords;
    firstCoords.latitude = lat1;
    firstCoords.longitude = lng1;

CLLocationCoordinate2D secondCoords;
    secondCoords.latitude=lat2;
    secondCoords.longitude=lng2;

NSLog(@" %f", lat1);
NSLog(@" %f", lng1);
NSLog(@" %f", lat2);
NSLog(@" %f", lng2);    
routeCoordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, lng1);
routeCoordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, lng2);
MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoordinates count:2];
[mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
```

Comment: routeCoordinates? what is it?